# Automatically create a CSV from a C++ file

Tags: c++, powershell, csv, notepad++

I got a GIS application that asks for a CSV as input, while the values for that CSV are generated by another GIS application in the following C++ format:

```
class _shape_0
{
objectType="waterbody";
class Arguments
{
    POSITION="[946.58899, 1087.7439, 0]";
    TYPE="01_SaltLake";
    ORIENTATION="45";
};
 };
class _shape_1
{
objectType="vegetation";
class Arguments
{
    POSITION="[962.88275, 1087.9946, 0]";
    TYPE="02_PineWoods";
    ORIENTATION="270";
};
  };
    class _shape_2
 {
objectType="vegetation";
class Arguments
{
    POSITION="[941.5755, 1068.6926, 0]";
    TYPE="03_Wheatcrop";
    ORIENTATION="135";
};

    and so on...
```

Because the output file contains hundreds of items, I would like to use an automated script that converts **POSITION, TYPE and ORIENTATION** from that output c++ file into a CSV, looking like this:

```
TYPE, POSITION [X, Y, Z], ORIENTATION
03_Wheatcrop, 941.5755, 1068.6926, 0, 135
02_PineWoods, 962.88275, 1087.9946, 0, 270
01_SaltLake, 946.58899, 1087.7439, 0, 45
```

Is there a way to do it by powerscript or something similar? Using notepad++ and its regular expressions would also be an option for me, although I'd prefer an automated script.

Comment: I am curios, why you dont format it right in the c++ serializer?

Comment: That's not C++. It's _similar_ to C++ but not C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick and dirty solution that depends on fixed row order is easy enough. Should the record internal order vary, more complex an approach is needed.

If the order of records change, like sometimes `TYPE` is before `POSITION` and sometimes not, the parser must be re-implemented. A state machine that tracks keywords and some regular expressions should work in such a case.

The idea for simple solution is to read the file and loop through all the rows. If a row containing `POSITION` is found, let's pick it and two next rows. Remove extra chars and create a formatted string. Finally, save all the stuff on a file. This doesn't use proper CSV output, so if a field contains a value that needs escaping, the script breaks. Should that be the case, more complex an approach based on custom objects and `export-csv` is needed.

```
$d = get-content  c:\temp\infile.dat # Read the incoming C++ish file
$rows = @() # Empty array for results
$rows += "TYPE, POSITION [X, Y, Z], ORIENTATION" #Header row
for ($i=0; $i -le $d.count -2; ++$i) { # Loop through the data
  if( $d[$i] -match "POSITION" ) { # POSITION element, let's pick it and two next lines
     $pos = $d[$i].Replace('POSITION="[', '').Replace(']";', '').Replace(' ', '') # Remove extra chars
     $typ = $d[$i+1].Replace('TYPE="', '').Replace('";', '').Replace(' ', '')
     $ori = $d[$i+2].Replace('ORIENTATION="', '').Replace('";', '').Replace(' ', '')
     $rows += $("{0}, {1}, {2}" -f $typ, $pos, $ori ) # Add formatted string to array
  } 
}

set-content -path c:\temp\out.csv -value $rows # Write output to a file.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! order stays the same all the time, so I hope it will work. Will test when back from work...